# Android http 403 error

Tags: android, http, request

I have some troubles when doing request to an API, it gives me a 401 error.
The request is made by using a token, and I'm making several other request with that same token, and it works fine, it' just that particular request.
To finish, I'm trying to do that request with postman and it works perfectly fine.

-- EDIT --

```
private void run() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        //Initializing Url
        URL url = new URL(urlStr);
        //Creating an httmlurl connection
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        //Configuring connection properties
        conn.setReadTimeout(150000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(150000);
        conn.setRequestMethod(requestType);
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        //Creating an output stream
        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        //We are using a method getPostDataString which is defined below
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(getPostDataString(params));
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();
        int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        Log.d("HTTP", "Code: " + responseCode);
        if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            String response;
            //Reading server response
            while ((response = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(response);
            }
        }

        if (!(sb.toString().isEmpty()))
            this.response = sb.toString();
        else
        {
            this.response = queryResponse.WRONG;
        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {e.printStackTrace();} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {e.printStackTrace();} catch (ProtocolException e) {e.printStackTrace();} catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

Comment: can you please post your code?

Comment: It might be because of cookie

Comment: I can post the code that makes the request, yes